# Determine number of commit ahead and behind using JGit

Tags: jgit

On a GitHub project, when we go to any branches page, we can see graphs which describes commit ahead/behind numbers of a branch w.r.t. master.

How can we determine those ahead behind numbers using JGit?

I used `BranchTrackingStatus` class for this, but I'm getting `BranchTrackingStatus` object always null.

Here is the code which I used

```java
private static Lis<Integer> getCounts(Repository repository, String branchName) throws IOException{
  BranchTrackingStatus trackingStatus = BranchTrackingStatus.of(repository, branchName);
  List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  if (trackingStatus != null){
      counts.add(trackingStatus.getAheadCount());
      counts.add(trackingStatus.getBehindCount());
  } else {
      counts.add(0);
      counts.add(0);
  }
  return counts;
}

public void show(String repoName, String baseBranchName) throws IOException, GitAPIException{    

  Repository repository = repoManager.openRepository(new Project.NameKey(repoName));

  List<Ref> call = new Git(repository).branchList().call();
  for (Ref ref : call) {
    List<Integer> counts = getCounts(repository, ref.getName());
    System.out.println("Commits ahead : "+counts.get(0));
    System.out.println("Commits behind : "+counts.get(1));
  }
}
```

Comment: The output of 'git rmeote -v' and a 'git status' on the commandline will allow others to verify that the local git repository is in a state that has remote branch differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BranchTrackingStatus.of()` assumes that `branchName` denotes a local branch, either by its full name (e.g. `refs/heads/master`) or its short name (e.g. `master`). It returns `null` if the given `branchName` cannot be found or the tracking branch is not configured or does not exist.

To compare two arbitrary branches, you could adopt the `BranchTrackingStatus` code like so:

```java
void calculateDivergence(Ref local, Ref tracking) throws IOException {
  try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
    RevCommit localCommit = walk.parseCommit(local.getObjectId());
    RevCommit trackingCommit = walk.parseCommit(tracking.getObjectId());
    walk.setRevFilter(RevFilter.MERGE_BASE);
    walk.markStart(localCommit);
    walk.markStart(trackingCommit);
    RevCommit mergeBase = walk.next();
    walk.reset();
    walk.setRevFilter(RevFilter.ALL);
    aheadCount = RevWalkUtils.count(walk, localCommit, mergeBase);
    behindCount = RevWalkUtils.count(walk, trackingCommit, mergeBase);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine to me, I took some of it and added it as a sample in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/ShowBranchTrackingStatus.java) to see if it works. Locally I see counts when there are actual differences to the remote repostory.

Please note how BranchTrackingStatus works: It will not do a remote request and fetch the latest commits from the remote side, but it will only show what the local git repository has on the remote-tracking branches compared to the local branches.

I.e. you probably need to do a [git fetch](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/FetchRemoteCommits.java) first on a repository that has updates on the remote side in order to get the status of the remote repository updated and only then BranchTrackingStatus will show values.