# egit: how to know how much local branch is ahead/behind tracking branch

Tags: egit

We can get the details of number of commits made in the local and the number of commit the local branch is behind in Eclipse in the Project Explorer/Package Explorer/GIT Repository View (with up and down arrows and numbers).

How do we get the information about the commits made in local branch which have to be pushed to the remote and the commits pushed to the remote by others which should be pulled?

Answer (score 0):

Goto Team -> Show in the History.

This view will give you all the details about the commits you have made and ahead of other. The commits other have made and pushed in which you are behind.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the question is duplicated ([Determine number of commit ahead and behind using JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605838/determine-number-of-commit-ahead-and-behind-using-jgit)) and I should search for "jgit" instead of "egit".